# ShareActionProvider only for menu item?

Tags: android, user-interface

Due to some dialog issue, i cannot use createChooser method to intent the **ACTION_SEND**, i have to build my own listview on a standard Activity with share action.

However, i found that only menu item has actionProviderClass property : `android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"`

How any way i can build my own share action list?

Below is the code how the ShareActionProvider works:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    /** Inflating the current activity's menu with res/menu/items.xml */
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu);

    /** Getting the actionprovider associated with the menu item whose id is share */
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share).getActionProvider();

    /** Setting a share intent */
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

// Call to update the share intent
private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    }
}

   /** Returns a share intent */
private Intent getDefaultShareIntent(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "SUBJECT");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Extra Text");
    return intent;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PackageManager.queryIntentActivities(Intent, int)` to get a list of activities and services that can handle a given Intent.

```java
final List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
for (Iterator<ResolveInfo> iter = resolveInfos.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    ResolveInfo resolveInfo = iter.next();
    if (resolveInfo.activityInfo != null) {
        final Drawable icon = resolveInfo.loadIcon(PackageManager);
        final String title = resolveInfo.loadLabel(PackageManager);
    }
}
```